# How to populate listbox of MS access on Button Click Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sub in VBA where I am fetching data from database on button click event 
like below

```
Public Sub getNearestPfk(runNR As Integer)
Dim DB As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset
Dim sqlString As String
Dim record As Object
Dim objPFK As Pfk

Dim i As Integer

i = 0


Set DB = CurrentDb
sqlString = " SELECT TOP 5 T_TEMP_DESTANCE_CAL.* FROM T_TEMP_DESTANCE_CAL WHERE RUNID = " & runNR & " ORDER by DISTANCE "
MsgBox (sqlStringGetNearestPFK)

Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset(sqlString)

Do Until rs.EOF

objPFK.ID = rs!ID
objPFK.fistName = rs!firstName
objPFK.lastName = rs!lastName
objPFK.distance = rs!distance
objPFK.duration = rs!duration
objPFK.address = rs!address

arrayObjPFK(i) = objPFK


rs.MoveNext
i = i + 1
Loop


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing


End Sub
```

Now I have all the data Which I want to display

how should I display this data in listbox so on this button click a listbox will populate

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/ff196460.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can set the list box property called [Row Source Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821440.aspx) to `Table/Query` and then your [Row Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196460.aspx) property to the SQL statement.

If you want to update the list box, simply update the Row Source.